# Display elements in scope in angularjs page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

Hy everybody, first question here.
I'm learning angularjs and right now i'm stuck on "Controller and Scope" chapter.
I'm trying to search trough an array of objects and show items that match my query; unfortunately my screen stays blank.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>Search and print with Scope</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="CPU" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="proc in cpu | filter:q">
                {{proc.house}} - {{proc.model}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Controller($scope)
            $scope.cpu = [
            { house: 'Intel', model: 'I7' },
            { house: 'AMD', model: 'Ryzen' },
            { house: 'Qualcomm', modello: 'Snapdragon' }
            ];
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong?

---

EDIT for EDIT:Just for those who might look at this question, my error was to call ng-app twice, once in the html tag and once in body tag.

EDIT: I'm here again; I modified the code using the given answers, but I still got a search box and a blank screen. I doubt is code related since I also tried to simply copy and paste it in a new file but i got the same result. What could be?
Code is down here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', [])

    app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
      $scope.cpu = [{
          house: 'Intel',
          model: 'I7'
        },
        {
          house: 'AMD',
          model: 'Ryzen'
        },
        {
          house: 'Qualcomm',
          model: 'Snapdragon'
        }
      ];
    });
  </script>
  <title>Search and print with Scope</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="CPU" />
    <ul>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li ng-repeat="proc in cpu">
        {{proc.house}} - {{proc.model}}
      </li>
      <li>hi again</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are trying to get the scope data before declaring it, you need to load the script before using `ng-repeat`, so move the `script` before the div definition.

Also you are not correctly defining the Controller, it should be defined within an `app` module, then bind the `ng-app` and the `Controller` in your HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>Search and print with Scope</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('angularApp',[])

        app.controller('Controller',function($scope){
           $scope.cpu = [
           { house: 'Intel', model: 'I7' },
           { house: 'AMD', model: 'Ryzen' },
           { house: 'Qualcomm', modello: 'Snapdragon' }
           ];
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="CPU" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="proc in cpu | filter:q">
                {{proc.house}} - {{proc.model}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a  angular module and ng-app mentioned as below

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])

app.controller('Controller',function($scope){
            $scope.cpu = [
            { house: 'Intel', model: 'I7' },
            { house: 'AMD', model: 'Ryzen' },
            { house: 'Qualcomm', modello: 'Snapdragon' }
            ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Search and print with Scope</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="CPU" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="proc in cpu | filter:q">
                {{proc.house}} - {{proc.model}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer

Comment: Mark as answer if that helped